# PostgreSQL: Python cannot save array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, feature-extraction

I have an array of strings. Each row of the string contains 1440 "numbers". Using the code below the program runs fine but when I check the feature column via pgAdmin it is empty. The column "image" which contains the path of the image and is primary key, is filled correctly. If I try to save the feature into "image" columns I get an error that there is now enough space:

> **index row size 2896 exceeds maximum 2712 for index**

But I don't think that this is a problem when I save the array into "feature"  column because I get no error.

```
for imagePath in glob.glob(args["dataset"] + "/*.jpg"):
    # Get the image
    imageID = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)

    # Find the features
    features = cd.describe(image)

    # Put the features into DB
    features = [str(f) for f in features]
    cursor.execute("insert into index (image,feature) values (%s,%s);",  (imageID,features))
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

**UPDATE:** It seems that it was a pgAdmin related problem, because if I fetch the column I get all the numbers.

Comment: What's your schema for this table?

Comment: Nothing special, text for both columns. "Image" column is a primary key.

Comment: Do you have "image" as a primary key? This is not going to work. The key is never supposed to be that large.

Answer (score 1):

you have an index on a column, and you are trying to insert data that is too wide for that index.
if you don't need ordering on that index switching to a hash index may be a good solution, else you need to rethink it.